# SSIS, Looping text file and Decision making

Tags: ssis

I have 3 text files (.txt) in the folder "d:\testfolder\" .

1. Student20170201.txt
2. Class20170201.txt
3. Subject20170201.txt

I need to loop all the text files in the given folder and store them accordingly to their specific tables(sql).

How can I achieve this using SSIS package. Thanks.!

Comment: You need a Foreach Loop Container in control flow and put data flow task inside the container

Answer (score 0):

Posted in Microsoft help and i got the solution. Please click the below link,

https://lijithkp.blogspot.in/2015/11/ssis-loading-multiple-text-files-into.html